# Problem with macro

Tags: macros, xstring

I can not understand why this latex code 
does not work as expected:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\doparamG}[2]{%
\StrCut{#2}{"}\LeftString\RightString%
\doparam{#1}{\LeftString}%
\StrCut{\RightString}{"}\RLeftString\RRightString%
\StrLen{\RLeftString}[\rlstrLen]%
\StrLen{\RRightString}[\rrstrLen]%
\ifnum\rlstrLen > 0 M:#1{\RLeftString}\fi%
\ifnum\rrstrLen > 0 \doparamG{#1}{\RRightString}\fi%
}

\newcommand{\doparam}[2]{%
\StrCut{#2}{ }\LeftString\RightString%
\StrLen{\LeftString}[\lstrLen]%
\StrLen{\RightString}[\rstrLen]%
\ifnum\lstrLen > 0 #1{\LeftString}\fi%
\ifnum\rstrLen > 0 \doparam{#1}{\RightString}\fi%
}

\newcommand{\doparamGDEBUG}[2]{%
\StrCut{#2}{"}\LeftString\RightString%
Left:\LeftString\\%
\StrCut{\RightString}{"}\RLeftString\RRightString%
\StrLen{\RLeftString}[\rlstrLen]%
\StrLen{\RRightString}[\rrstrLen]%
Middle:\RLeftString ,len: \rlstrLen\\%\ifnum\rlstrLen > 0 #1{\RLeftString}\fi%
Right:\RRightString ,len: \rrstrLen\\%\ifnum\rrstrLen > 0 \doparamGDBG{#1}{\RRightString}\fi%
\ifnum\rrstrLen > 0 \doparamGDEBUG{#1}{\RRightString}\fi%
}

\newcommand{\justnewline}[1]{#1\\}

\begin{document}
Simple test:\\
\doparam{\justnewline}{ line1 line2   line3 }
\doparamG{\justnewline}{ "line 4" line5   "line 6" }

But we have:\\
\doparamGDEBUG{\justnewline}{ "line 4" line5   "line 6" }

\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the expected behaviour?

Comment: Note the warnings about bad boxes are due to misuse of `\\ ` which should never be used at the end of a paragraph. Apart from that unless you say what your expectation is, hard to say how that differs from what the code does.

Comment: I expect "line 4" in a new line  after "line3", and "line5" and "line 6" for next lines. Compare output of <doparamGDEBUG> with output

Comment: .. with output of <doparamG> which has no output!

Comment: but you should say in words what the code is trying to do, I would guess that it is trying to replace every space not inside `".."` with `\\ ` is that right?

Comment: <doparam> run some command on each word of a string (seperated by spaces) and works fine. But <doparamG> wants to allow you gather some words using " as "one parameter". <doparamG> does not work at all.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative with `expl3` and some hackery.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand\justpar[1]{#1\par}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand \doparam { O{\justpar} m }
 {
  \abdollah_doparam:Nn #1 { #2 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \abdollah_doparam:Nn #1 #2
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #2 }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { " } { \abdollah_doparam_quote:w }
  \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \l_tmpa_tl }
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l_tmpa_seq { ~ } \l_tmpa_tl
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { \tl_if_empty:nF {##1} { #1 {##1} } } 
 }
\cs_new:Npn \abdollah_doparam_quote:w #1 \abdollah_doparam_quote:w { { #1 } }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\doparam{ line1 line2   line3  "line 4" line5   "line 6" }

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dear @Manuel, it works but generates errors.  pdflatex's last message is <l.28 ...line2   line3  "line 4" line5   "line 6" }>.

Comment: It works for me.

Comment: `\seq_show:N` looks like a leftover

Comment: @clemens It definitely was :) I just removed that line.